# Row selection KoGrid

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kogrid

I am workign with Ko Grid and I am binding an array of observable to the Grid. Now, I do not see much documentation about selection mechanism. I would like to operate on selected rows in the grid when user selects particular rows.

Anyone has any good example or reference on this topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list of all configurations for `koGrid`: https://github.com/ericmbarnard/KoGrid/wiki/Configuration

You should add some the following properties depends on desired behavior: `isMultiSelect`, `selectedItem`, `selectedItem`.

Here is an example from documentation:

```
<div data-bind="koGrid: { data: myObsArray,
                           isMultiSelect: false,
                           selectedItem: mySelectedObj,
                           columnDefs: [ { field: 'firstName', displayName: 'First Name' }]"></div>
```